# jQuery set time out

Tags: jquery

I need a function that will do the following.

It will immediately let a DIV show and after 5 seconds it should disappear.

I am fine with showing and hiding a DIV, but I do not know how to mix this with the set time out functionality.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("div").show('fast').delay(5000).hide('fast');
```

Of course you should adjust selector according to your actual markup.